# USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT when trying to get Envelope Status or Documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API to make various calls, and this is the only one I've had problems with. Basically the account has a bunch of users with reduced permissions (Permissions to send documents, work with the API, send on behalf of user, and allow receipt of transferred documents (?))

There have been no issues using the createEnvelope call, using the exact same configuration, but for some reason I'm having issues using the EnvelopeDocuments:get call. I've tried setting it up following the guides, and am currently using Postman to test this, but I keep getting that error above and I can find nothing on what would cause this:

I'm making the call to

```
https://docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{main account GUID}/envelopes/{Envelope ID}
```

The envelope is definitely on the live platform, not the sandbox. The account ID is the second value found right at the top of the API and Keys pages. To authenticate, I'm using the same Access Token as I did to send the envelope.

The envelope is sent as a non-admin user, I don't know if that has anything to do with it? Is there a permission that needs to be set?

The same call worked on the Sandbox platform, but on that one the user who had sent the envelope was also the main account user.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if I need to supply more information!

Comment: `https://docusign.net` is not a valid docusign endpoint

Comment: I’m an idiot and copied it wrong, my bad! I meant .com, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: correction: .net IS the correct endpoint for this call, I'm pretty sure. Else I think I'd be getting a bigger error back,

Comment: the `.net` part is correct, the issue is that you were hitting `docusign.net` without a subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue and it was to do with the endpoint. I was confused because the endpoint referred to DOES actually work for other requests. But for this request/user combination it ended up being:

```
https://eu.docusign.net
```

Silly mistake on my part, but I'm glad I finally got it working.

The following articles on DocuSign helped me figure it out:

- https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/post-go-live
- https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints

Answer (score 2):

Note in DocuSign, there are two different IDs:

1. AccountID - which reference the overall account, which can contain many users.
2. UserId - which reference the specific individual user.

You specify both in your API call. The accountId is part of your endpoint URL, the userId is coming from the authentication token you used.

If this userId is not part of this account Id - you will get this error message.

Please check and confirm these IDs to fix this issue.

Also, note that yes, you have to match the enviornment as well. demo.docusign.net would be Sandbox and www.docusign.net would be production. Your accountId and userId and envelopeId must all be from the same environment.

Comment: The userid used in the authentication is part of the same account as the accountid used in the API call. In that the user exists for that account.. I’m not sure if I need to add them anywhere or give any extra permissions to make them explicitly part of the account?

Comment: What about the envelopeID ? Is it from the same account as well,?

Comment: Yeah, User, Envelope and Account ID are all from the same DocuSign account